# IOS IBOutletCollection UITextView

Tags: ios, collections, uitextview

I want to implement something like [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) with text inside (Title, description, footer).

I thought to use a `IBOutletCollection` TextView, but I am open for other solutions.

I've linked from my xib file the collection to my interface.

In my class implementation :

```
@synthesize myTextViewCollection;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   myTextViewCollection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];

   for (UITextView *myView in myTextViewCollection) {
      NSLog(@"%@", myView);
      myView.text = @"any text";
   }
}
```

myView contain the three strings : "one", "two", "three".

**Output Error** :

```
-[__NSCFConstantString setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x461b8
```

I don't understand why i get this error ...

Thanks !

Comment: Because you're treating a string as a text view. Why are you doing `myTextViewCollection = [NSMutab...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the `IBOutlet`s for your text views?  You want something like this:

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextView* textViewOne;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextView* textViewTwo;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextView* textViewThree;
```

Then:

```
for (UITextView *textView in @[ self.textViewOne, self.textViewTwo, self.textViewThree ]) {
    textView.text = @"any text";
}
```

What you have done is add a bunch of `NSString` literals to an array, then you're trying to send the `setText:` selector to an `NSString`, which is not a selector `NSString` responds to.

Comment: Ok, but in my interface class, myTextViewCollection is a TextView :
     
      `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITextView) NSArray *myTextViewCollection;`

Comment: Well then you should be able to just replace `@[ ... ]` in my example with `self.myTextViewCollection`?

Comment: I've done, but I get the same error.

Edit : It's Works ! Thanks

Comment: Try adding this in the loop before you set `text`: `NSLog(@"--> %@", NSStringFromClass([textView class]));`  See if the objects are the class you think they are.